# IntStream.iterate with alternating values to add

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, sequence

I want to create a sequence of integers, preferably as an `IntStream`, which follows a certain condition. some simple examples to explain what I am trying to do:

Sequence of first 10 even numbers starting from 0 (Here i have no problems, I do it with the below snippet)

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(10); 

//0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
```

Sequence of first 10 numbers starting from 0 by alternately adding 2 and 3 to the privious number; desired output:

```
 //0,2,5,7,10,12,15,17,20,22
```

I would love to use for this scenario also  `IntStream.iterate()` or `IntStream.generate()` but couldn't make it on my own. I am using classic for loops, which works but is somehow long for such a relative simple task

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0);
for(int i = 1, j = 1; i < 10; i++, j *= -1){
    if(j > 0){
        list.add(list.get(i-1) + 2);
    }
    else{
        list.add(list.get(i-1) + 3);
    }
}

//and then stream over the list to get IntStream
list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue);
```

Any easy way to achieve the same as above with  `IntStream.iterate()` or `IntStream.generate()`?

For three and more alternating values I am out of ideas how to do it elegantly. If for example I want to create the Sequence of first 10 numbers starting from 0 by alternately adding +2, +5 and +7 to the previous number with the desired output:

```
//0,2,7,14,16,21,28,30,35,42
```

I have thought about using `i%3` in a for loop with 3 if-else blocks or switch cases but this will grow when i need more alternating values and i have to add more `ifs` or `cases`. Any ideas how to do it? I am open for other approaches too if you think `IntStream.iterate()` or `IntStream.generate()` is not the proper way of solving the described task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at this mathematically. Say you want to add x1, x2, x3 ... xn, alternately.

The first n terms can be written as:

```
(0 * sum of all x's)
(0 * sum of all x's + x1)
(0 * sum of all x's + x1 + x2)
(0 * sum of all x's + x1 + x2 + x3)
...
(0 * sum of all x's + sum of all x's - xn)
```

The next n terms can be written the same way, except you replace all the 0s with 1s.

```
(1 * sum of all x's)
(1 * sum of all x's + x1)
(1 * sum of all x's + x1 + x2)
(1 * sum of all x's + x1 + x2 + x3)
...
(1 * sum of all x's + sum of all x's - xn)
```

And the *next* n terms you replace all the 1's with 2's, and so on.

So we just need to generate the stream (1, 2, 3, 4...) and `flatMap` each element `i` to the stream of

```
(i * sum of all x's)
(i * sum of all x's + x1)
(i * sum of all x's + x1 + x2)
(i * sum of all x's + x1 + x2 + x3)
...
(i * sum of all x's + sum of all x's - xn)
```

Using this pattern, you can write your 2, 5, 7 stream like this:

```
final int a = 2, 
final int b = 5, 
final int c = 7;
final int sum = a + b + c;
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).flatMap(
    i -> IntStream.of(i * sum, i * sum + a, i * sum + a + b)
).limit(10);
```

If you wanted to do 2,3,5,7 instead:

```
final int a = 2, 
final int b = 3, 
final int c = 5; 
final int d = 7;
final int sum = a + b + c + d;
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).flatMap(
    i -> IntStream.of(i * sum, i * sum + a, i * sum + a + b, i * sum + a + b + c)
).limit(10);
```

I'll leave it to you to generalise this to any `int[]` of numbers.

Answer (score 6):

To generate a stream by alternating adding 2 or 3, it can be observed that every *other* value will be a multiple of 5. Therefore if the previous value is divisible by 5 with no remainder, we should add 2, otherwise we should add 3.

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> (i % 5 == 0) ? (i + 2) : (i + 3)).limit(10)
```

For two alternating integers, there will be cases where this approach is not possible. If one of the numbers is a factor of the other, that won't be possible. 2 and 4 for example.

For cases like those, you can use a more general approach and maintain a boolean outside the iterator.

It doesn't follow the functional style because your function has a side effect but hey, Java isn't a functional language. It's intuitive enough.

```
AtomicBoolean isTwo = new AtomicBoolean(true);
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> isTwo.getAndSet(!isTwo.get()) ? (i + 2) : (i + 4))
```

For 3 alternating values, in the general case you can do a similar thing to the boolean, but with an integer counter that cycles between 0, 1 and 2.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> {
        int count = counter.getAndUpdate(cnt -> (cnt + 1) % 3);
        if (count == 0) return i + 2;
        if (count == 1) return i + 5;
        if (count == 2) return i + 7;
        // As long as modulus value == number of if-conditions, this isn't possible
        throw new RuntimeException("Only 3 possible values");
    })
    .limit(10)
```

Comment: @nopens In this case the atomicity and thread-safety aspects are not relevant, we just need some mutable holder for a value (boolean and int respectively) which we can keep a constant reference to (variables captured by lambdas must be final). If there was such thing as MutableBoolean or MutableInt, that would serve our purposes here better. But all the primitive wrapper classes in Java are immutable. For our case, AtomicInteger/Boolean are *good enough*. There might be very slight performance gains if you wrote your own MutableBoolean, because you would avoid locking, but it's not important.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `AtomicInteger` to achieve this and keep of list of numbers that are to be added in an alternating manner.

```java
List<Integer> adds = List.of(2,3,7);
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);
int limit = 10;
return IntStream.iterate(1,
   i -> i + adds.get(x.getAndIncrement() % adds.size()))
                .limit(limit)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A very good approach. Learned something new about `AtomicInteger` .